# dropShadowEnabled no longer supported in Flex Hero build 17689

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder

I am using Flash Builder Buritto with the latest "nightly" Flex 4.5 SDK, build 17689.  It seems the dropShadowEnabled property is no longer supported with the Hero default skin.  I get this compilation error:

> The style 'dropShadowVisible' is only
>   supported by type
>   'spark.components.Panel' with the
>   theme(s) 'spark'.

Is there any way to disable the shadow without making a custom panel skin?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using a Halo skin, which really does not support the dropShadowVisible property.  Added a new skin which just disables the shadows.